# How to merge a certain column from all my dataframes contained in my list into a single column

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have 13 dataframes in my list. Each dataframe shares the same columns as others do. I would to create a new column called b which will contain all the columns called x from my 13 dataframes.Each dataframe has a column called x.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Some questions are straightforward enough not to need that.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
dflist <- list(iris, iris, iris)
b <- vector()
for(i in length(dflist)) b <- c(b,dflist[[i]]$Species)
```